# Command Window Unexpectedly Opens When Executing Delphi 10.4 program

Tags: windows, delphi

I have a fairly large system with a number of Delphi modules, all interacting.  For some reason, a command window started unexpectedly opening under the target app's window when I run a delphi program from the IDE environment or if I launch the program from shortcut.

If I copy all the source files to a new directory and rename the folders to their new value in the .dpr .dproj, etc files, and recompile the problem does not reoccur.  The problem seems to be spreading. In other words, modules that previously opened as expected now all of a sudden start launching a command prompt window labeled  "Terminal (3)" in the TaskMgr.  I have been using Delphi since version 2.1.  Is this a windows update problem as it just started happening? I am up-to-date on  Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.2283]

Comment: Sounds more like a corrupted project, of not a virus. You should try creating a new project from scratch and add your existing source files to it. If the problem persists, contact Embarcadero